# Devise not filling resource.errors in sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using the Devise gem and in the sign in page I expect that, if I don't write anything it should give me an error.  At first I thought I wasn't showing the error, but after doing this:

`<%= resource.errors.inspect %`>

After doing a sign in with no values at all, I get the following:

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x000000048ac1a0 @base=#<User id: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={}>
```

No messages at all.

I haven't modified the default Devise model or view, so it is pretty weird because in sign up and forget password I get the errors correctly.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Devise error messages for **sign in** are set in the flash hash. Try adding this in your **application** layout:

```
<%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
<%- end -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more convenient method is `<%= devise_error_messages! %>` ([documentation here](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/DeviseHelper#devise_error_messages%21-instance_method))